# Get headers from a Flowable response using the Micronaut Declarative Client

Tags: grails, micronaut

I am using the Micronaut declarative client to consume a backend API in a grails 4 app. I have successfully implemented some GET/POST/PUT and DELETE requests but now I want to implement a download endpoint, this endpoint returns a heavy zip file so I tried with:

```
@Get(value = '/download/{zipFileId}', processes = 'application/zip')
abstract Flowable<ByteBuffer<?>> downloadZip(Long zipFileId)
```

and it works but I don't know how to get some headers like 'Content-Length' from that response, so, my question is, there is a way to get the headers from a Flowable response using the Micronaut Declarative Client?

I tried the low level client and it is working with:

```
Flowable<HttpResponse<ByteBuffer<?>>> response = rxStreamingHttpClient.exchangeStream(request)
response.blockingSubscribe(new Subscriber<HttpResponse<ByteBuffer<?>>>() {
    int number = 0

    ...

    @Override
    void onNext(HttpResponse<ByteBuffer<?>> httpResponse) {
        ByteBuffer<?> buffer = byteBufferHttpResponse.body()
        if(number == 0) {
            httpServletResponse.setHeader('Content-Length', httpResponse.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        }
        IOUtils.copyLarge(buffer.toInputStream(), httpServletResponse.getOutputStream())
        ((ReferenceCounted) buffer).release()
        number++
        subscription.request(1)
    }

    ...

})
```

I tried in the declarative client with

```
@Get(value = '/download/{zipFileId}', processes = 'application/zip')
Flowable<HttpResponse<ByteBuffer<?>>> downloadZip(Long zipFileId)
```

but it looks like the client download all the file before call onNext in the subscriber (and I am getting a

```
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
```

when I try to access the buffer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the response data, but also stream the content, you can do:

`HttpResponse<Flowable<ByteBuffer<?>>> downloadZip(Long zipFileId)`

The response body will be a flowable you can subscribe to then